# R question with masked from and connection error

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to install a warning system on R, but I am having a lot of problems with it. I have been following the instructions from my class but when I go to run the app I get either error in file: cannot open the connection or permission denied. https://ilias.uni-freiburg.de/goto.php?target=file_2670067_download&client_id=unifreiburg

I've attached the directions and have tried to download it on an earlier R 4.1.3 but still have issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

> shiny::runApp('C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/Temp1_Ewars_Plus_local-main (2).zip/Ewars_Plus_local-main')
> Loading required package: shiny

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3237
Loading required package: ggplot2

Attaching package: ‘plotly’

The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

```
last_plot
```

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

```
filter
```

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

```
layout
```

Attaching package: ‘shinydashboardPlus’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

```
box
```

Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:shinydashboardPlus’:

```
box, dashboardHeader, dashboardPage,
dashboardSidebar, messageItem, notificationItem,
taskItem
```

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

```
box
```

Find out what's new in shinyjs:
https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/releases

Attaching package: ‘shinyjs’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

```
runExample
```

The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:

```
removeClass, show
```

Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

```
as.Date, as.Date.numeric
```

Attaching package: ‘leaflet’

The following object is masked from ‘package:xts’:

```
addLegend
```

Warning in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
cannot open file 'objects in UI.R': No such file or directory
Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection
72: file
71: source

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The link you have provided is not accessible without logging in. Please provide us with a [reproducible example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help). Warnings like *The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’* 
 provide you with the information, that there is a namespace conflict (two or more libraries using the same name for a function). Use e.g. `shinydashboardPlus::box` to specify which function you want to call. The `cannot open file` warning is self-explanatory.